# Verificando se dado persistiu com sucesso

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, persistência

Qual seria a melhor maneira de obter um `bool` indicando se o método `Add()` e depois `SaveChanges()` foi realizado com sucesso?

Estou tentando assim? Será que está correto?

```
public bool IncluirRegistro(Pessoa tEntEF)
    {
        db.Pessoa.Add(tEntEF);
        int DadosSalvos = db.SaveChanges();
        return (DadosSalvos > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do tipo de problema que você espera ter. Se for só erro de lógica me parece que esta é a melhor forma mesmo. Ela já diz se alguma operação persistiu ou não.

Mas pode não ter persistido por uma série de razões que o próprio EF informação através de exceção, aí só capturando uma exceção para saber.

Sempre capture as exceções esperadas e que pode fazer algo a respeito. Nunca capture por capturar e menos ainda capture `Exception`. [Leia a documentação para saber todas exceções possíveis neste método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads). Você não precisa tratar aí todas as exceções. É muito comum em quase todos os códigos que vejo aqui o uso errado de exceções.

Algo assim seria interessante:

```
public bool IncluirRegistro(Pessoa tEntEF) {
    try {
        db.Pessoa.Add(tEntEF);
        int DadosSalvos = ;
        return (db.SaveChanges() > 0);
    } catch (DbUpdateException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Database.cs).

Comment: Aqui ficaria a faltar adicionar outro catch para recolher qualquer outro tipo de excepçao.. Senao a aplicacao nao iria lidar com essa excepcao e rebenta o codigo.

Comment: @sir_ask Pode até precisar capturar outra exceção específica, mas capturar `Exception` é um erro porque está escondendo um possível erro de programação. Erros de programação não podem passar batido. Não acho o local adequado, mas até poderia capturar `Exception` para fazer outra coisa, tipo *logar* o problema e encerrar a aplicação. Erros de programação não devem ser escondidos, devem ser resolvidos. Erros de programação devem ser tratados em contexto mais geral. Tem bastante informação a respeito: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: completamente de acordo... ele teria que tratar a excepcao, agora o seu objectivo e saber se foi com sucesso ou nao, se deu erro nao teve sucesso e aplicacao nao pode estoirar, agora claro esta.. politica to try catch, sera no catch tratar do problema ou arquivar o problema tal como disseste!

Comment: @Maniero como sempre arrebentando nas respostas. Muito obrigado! Só complementando minha questão, o principal objetivo é capturar erros do banco... Tipo o comando update falhar pq um campo obrigatório estava null, ou uma chave não existia na outra tabela. Claro que estou validando os dados antes de enviar, mas vai que passa algo.

Comment: @sir_ask se capturar `Exception` e retornar `false` parece que é só um problema do banco de dados e pode ser muito mais sério. Sempre que não sabe qual é a exceção específica não pode tomar uma ação específica. E sem saber o que fazer não pode confiar mais na execução da aplicação, a única coisa certa a se fazer é quebrar a aplicação o mais rápido que der, no máximo deveria *logar* o problema.Como raramente isto dá problema as pessoas negligenciam isto, mas quando dá a pessoa não sabe como resolver porque sequer tem subsídios certos.Tem um monte de aplicação por aí que parece uma Brasília véia

Answer (score 1):

Com um try/catch, no caso de falhar o Add ou o savechanges é lançada uma excepcao.

```
public bool IncluirRegistro(Pessoa tEntEF)
    {
try{
        db.Pessoa.Add(tEntEF);
        int DadosSalvos = db.SaveChanges();
return true;
}
catch(Exception e){
return false;
}

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Só complementando minha questão, o principal objetivo é capturar erros do banco... Tipo o comando update falhar pq um campo obrigatório estava null, ou uma chave não existia na outra tabela. Claro que estou validando os dados antes de enviar, mas vai que passa algo.